# NoMethodError (undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass): while creating the new record in single table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am new to ROR and I am trying to create records in table, namely consultants using active records. But getting an error

> NoMethodError (undefined method 'create' for nil: NilClass): at
>   create(self.params)

```
class CreateConsultant <   Struct.new(:params)
  # Returns the newly created user
  def run
    consultant = Tutconsultant::Stores::EntityStore.for(
      Tutconsultant::Entities::Consultant).create(self.params)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you dont have create method. You should add a create method in your controller.

```
def create
   //your create codes here
end
```

Comment: I have create method in controller but its name is create_controller and the code looks like this: 
def create_consultant
       consultant = Tutconsultant::Interactors::Accounts::CreateConsultant.new({:firstname , :lastname, :email}).run
end

Comment: It is looking for create method in your controller. This is what I mean,

In controller:

def create
   consultant = Tutconsultant::Stores::EntityStore.for(
        Tutconsultant::Entities::Consultant).create(self.params)
end

In routes:
resources :your_model

Comment: Again the same error at create method in controller.

Comment: I guess you are not in a proper controller. Because if you add the create method in the proper controller it won't return the same error "undefined method create" because it is already here.

In your code is seems that you want to create a record. So this would be a simpliest way to do.

def create
    @model = Model.create(model_params)
end